# SQL - filter based on the Wildcard character

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to filter the value '**ECE/ABC1**' from my where clause based on wildcard characters and was trying the below query, but its not working.

Do you have any better approach ?

```
Select column1 from table
WHERE 
LIKE '%[A-Z][:slash:][A-Z]%'
```

Comment: It should be `WHERE somefield LIKE ..`.

Comment: You want to filter the exact value 'ECE/ABC1' or a regular expression which looks similar to the one that you have shared? 
And also mention if you are working on SQL Server or MySQL? as you have tagged your question in both the categories.

Comment: Yes. Identify what database platform you're working with as a start point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT my_column
FROM   my_table
WHERE  my_column LIKE '%/%'
```